# React-native Unable to resolve module styled-components/native

Tags: typescript, react-native

The import

`import styled, {ThemeProvider} from 'styled-components/native';`

package

`@types/styled-components-react-native`

tsconfig.json

```
// prettier-ignore
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",     /* Recommended React Native TSConfig base */
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */
  "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
  "types": ["@types/styled-components-react-native"],
    /* Completeness */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
}
```

Adding types in tsconfig.json removes typescript complaint and I can actually navigate to the package. but when I run build get the following error nonetheles.

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module styled-components/native from /home/bihire/development/react-native/elika_homes/src/shared/ThemeProvider.tsx: styled-components/native could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  2 | import React from 'react';
  3 | import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';
> 4 | import styled, {ThemeProvider} from 'styled-components/native';
```

Anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: You have a file called `ThemeProvider.tsx` and inside that you are using styled-component's `ThemeProvider`. Check if there is any name clash

Comment: changed file name and it ain't the problem @vinayr

Answer (score 0):

You must import `ThemeProvide` form the `styled-components` directly :

```
import {ThemeProvider} from 'styled-components';
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: The OP has that import. Please check the code in the question.